# Bootable usb stick not boots

Tags: boot, dual-boot, usb, live-usb

i have problem.

My bootable usb stick not boots any linux distribution.. it just stop at BIOS, like before turning on OS, but it does nothing.
Windows xp/7/8.1 installs boots perfectly.
It stopped booting every linux dist. after windows 8.1 installation.
Later i deleted windows 8.1 and installed windows 7, and now i want to install ubuntu from usb, but i cant(From disk every linuxOS boots perfectly but not from usb)
My computer now is like ~7years old.

Specs:

CPU: AMD Athlon 64 X2 5000+

Motherboard: GIGABYTE GA-M56S-S3

Video card: Nvidia n210

EDIT:
It boots on my other laptop..its bootable, but from this.. NOpe,  only windows installs

Comment: Plug your Linux USB into the system while it is off, and then turn it on.  As soon as you press the power button, repeatedly press F12 to access the boot menu.  Does your USB appear on the list of devices?  If so select the USB to boot it.  Also, may I ask what utility you used to create your Linux USB?

Comment: I doing it, nothing..Bios see USB but not boots linux.. I tried,Rufus universal usb installer and unetbootin..

Comment: Perhaps you can try older versions of Ubuntu - say, 12.04 or even 10.04?  That way we can rule out the possibility that a recent kernel change made your computer incompatible with the latest Linux.

Comment: Pavarotia, did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried opening the BIOS menu (Like you did to get it to boot from CD/DVD) and setting "USB-ZIP" as the first boot device?

Comment: Yup,i tried that, not works, and i dont get it, windows installation images boots perfect, but ubuntu/linux mint/elementary not..any linux not boots...

Answer (score 0):

Try using Unetbootin for making the USB stick boot.

Comment: I tried Rufus, universal usb installer and Unetbootin,nope not works